# Smallest constant in exponent so that limit of sum is $0$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to work out the smallest constant $c>0$ so that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{a=1}^n \sum_{b=0}^n {n \choose a} {n-a \choose b} \left({a+b \choose a} 2^{-a-b}\right)^{c n/\ln{n}} =0 .$$

If $c =3$ I can see that it certainly does and if $c=2$ it appears not to. How can you work out the constant exactly?

My current guess from a crude use of Stirling's approximation is that $c> 6/e$ is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Have you tried approximating the binomial coefficients with e.g. Stirling's approximation, and replacing the summations with integrals?

Comment: Could you please add your work to the question, and show how you got to $6/e$? (If it's a complete answer, you can also post it as an answer below.)

Comment: @TMM I just noticed that $\sum_{a=0}^n \sum_{b=0}^n {n \choose a} {n-a \choose b} = 3^n$ and guess that $\left({a+b \choose a} 2^{-a-b}\right)$ is bounded above by ${n \choose n/2} 2^{-n}$ then applied Stirling's approximation to this central binomial coefficient. As I say, it's just a guess.

Comment: That sounds like more than just a guess. The terms of the double summation that will dominate are indeed those terms with $a, b \approx n/2$, and for those terms you can use Stirling to get a good estimate. Proving that this is correct is another thing, but your intuition does seem right. And perhaps you can verify your guess numerically by evaluating the expression for $c$ close to $6/e$?

Comment: @TMM I did my best at testing it numerically before posting my guess :) My crude numerical tests are not 100% convincing however as log grows slowly and the individual terms in the sum can be very large making it all seem numerically unstable using limited precision arithmetic.

Comment: @TMM http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661281/how-to-maximize-leftab-choose-a-2-a-b-right/661302 suggests my guess is completely wrong at least in terms of which terms of the sum are largest.  Why did you feel that the erms of the double summation that will dominate are indeed those terms with $a,b\approx n/2$?

Comment: True, the terms with $a, b \approx n/2$ may not strictly be the largest of the double summation, but the terms with say $a, b \approx 10$ are much fewer in numbers, and so together they will contribute less to the double summation than the many terms with $a,b \approx n/2$. (But this is all hand-waving and intuition; like I said, proving your guess is true is another story.)

Comment: Using Stirling's approximation for the central binomial coefficient, I end up with $c > \ln 9 \approx 2.19722$ which is just a bit smaller than your $c > 6/e \approx 2.20728$.

Answer (score 6):

Let us first give the double summation a name:

$$S_n = \sum_{a=1}^n \sum_{b=0}^n {n \choose a} {n-a \choose b} \left({a+b \choose a} 2^{-a-b}\right)^{c n/\ln{n}}.$$

Now looking at the binomial coefficient ${n-a \choose b}$ we see that the terms with $b > n - a$ play no role. So we could also have taken the sum from $b = 0$ to $n - a$:

$$S_n = \sum_{a=1}^n \sum_{b=0}^{n-a} {n \choose a} {n-a \choose b} \left({a+b \choose a} 2^{-a-b}\right)^{c n/\ln{n}}.$$

Next, we can see more structure if we change the indices of the double summation from summing over $a,b$ to summing over $k = a+b$ and $a$. Since $k$ runs from $1$ to $n$ and $a$ runs from $1$ to $k$ we then get

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{a=1}^k {n \choose a} {n-a \choose k-a} \left({k \choose a} 2^{-k}\right)^{c n/\ln{n}}.$$

We can further simplify the initial two binomials, by noting that $\binom{n}{a} \binom{n-a}{k-a} = \frac{n!}{a!(k-a)!(n-k)!} = \binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{a}$:

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} \sum_{a=1}^k {k \choose a} \left[{k \choose a} 2^{-k}\right]^{c n/\ln{n}}.$$

Considering the term inside the square brackets, we can get an upper bound on $S_n$ by replacing $a$ by $k/2$, and using $\binom{k}{k/2} \sim 2^k \cdot \sqrt{2 / (\pi k)}$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
S_n &\leq \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} \sum_{a=1}^k {k \choose a} \left[\max_A {k \choose A} 2^{-k}\right]^{c n/\ln{n}} \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} \left[{k \choose k/2} 2^{-k}\right]^{c n/\ln{n}} \sum_{a=1}^k {k \choose a} \\
 &\sim \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} 2^k \left[\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi k}}\right]^{c n/\ln{n}} \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} 2^k \exp\left(\frac{c n \ln(\frac{2}{\pi k})}{2 \ln n}\right) \\
 &= \exp\left(\frac{c n \ln(2/\pi)}{2 \ln n}\right) \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} 2^k \exp\left(- \frac{c n \ln k}{2 \ln n}\right) = T_n \\
&\left[= \exp\left(\frac{c n \ln(2/\pi)}{2 \ln n}\right) \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} \exp\left(k \ln 2 - \frac{c n \ln k}{2 \ln n}\right) \right]
\end{align}$$

Note in the last expression that the terms that will dominate the summation are those terms with $k \gg 0$; then both the exponential term and the binomial coefficients increase. On the other hand, when $k > n/2$ becomes too big, then at some point the terms will start to decrease again. But it is clear that the summation is dominated by terms with $k = O(n)$, and not the terms with $k = o(n)$. So if we replace the $\ln k$ by $\ln O(n)$ (but not the $2^k$ by $2^{O(n)}$), we can get an estimate for the upper bound $T_n$ as:

$$\begin{align}
S_n \leq T_n &\approx \exp\left(\frac{c n \ln(2/\pi)}{2 \ln n}\right) \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} 2^k \exp\left(- \frac{c n \ln O(n)}{2 \ln n}\right) \\
 &\approx \exp\left(\frac{c n \ln(2/\pi)}{2 \ln n} - \frac{c n \ln O(n)}{2 \ln n}\right) \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} 2^k \\
 &\stackrel{(a)}{=} \exp\left(-\frac{c n}{2} + O\left(\frac{n}{\ln n}\right)\right) 3^n \\
 &= \exp\left(\left(\ln(3)-\frac{c}{2}\right) n + O\left(\frac{n}{\ln n}\right)\right) \\
\end{align}.$$

Note that in (a), I used the fact that if $k = c_1 n$ for $0 < c_1 < 1$, then $\ln k = \ln c_1 n = \ln c_1 + \ln n = \ln n + O(1)$, meaning that this extra term disappears in the order term $O(n / \ln n)$. Finally, we want that $S_n \leq T_n = o(1)$, which means that $(\ln 3 - \frac{c}{2}) n = o(1)$, or in terms of $c$: $$c > \ln 9 \approx 2.19722.$$ 
Since $S_n \leq T_n$ and $T_n$ goes to zero for $c > \ln 9$, this shows that for $S_n = o(1)$ it suffices to take $c > \ln 9$. If $T_n$ is asymptotically tight then this bound is also necessary.

---

To verify the above result, the plot below shows numerics for $S_n$ for $\color{red}{c = 2.19}$ and $\color{blue}{c = 2.20}$. For $c = 2.19$ indeed it seems that $S_n \not\to 0$ for large $n$, while for $c = 2.20$ it looks like the curve tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. This does not prove anything, but since the red curve goes up at the end it does seem very likely that the turning point is above $2.19$, and since the blue curve seems to "accelerate" towards $0$ at $n \approx 200$, the turning point is probably below $2.20$ as well.

[image]

Comment: If you allow a=0 in the outer sum then the limit is 1 I think. You can't allow both a and b to be zero.

Comment: @Anush You are right; I thought that term would "disappear anyway for large $n$" but indeed it doesn't.

Comment: The numerics suggest your bound is very close to being right.  In particular, $c=2.2$ works.

Comment: However... try n = 2.195. This seems to tend to $0$.

Comment: @marcinm The numerics can give you a rough picture of the situation, but it won't tell you exactly where the turning point is. In the red curve you see that the curve goes up at some point, which does seem convincing evidence that the sum does not converge. For larger $c$ the start of the curve will be more and more like the blue curve, and the point where $S_n$ goes up will shift to the right, until at some point the curve does not go up anymore. Unfortunately the numerics are hard to compute for $n \gg 500$, so it's hard to zoom in on the interval $[2.19, 2.20]$.